# Missing graphics card

Tags: drivers, 18.04, amd-graphics, mate, switchable-graphics

Ubuntu Mate 18.04 on a laptop with two graphics cards. The Intel works just fine. but the AMD Radeon HD 8690M is nowhere to be seen. All my searching has suggested with starting by checking additional drivers. The problem is that shows as completely empty.

Edit:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Dell 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520]
    Subsystem: Dell Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

So it is, in fact, there. Now how do I get the dang thing to recognize it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adaper is not missing. It is up and running.

You can run programs using this adapter with `DRI_PRIME=1` prefix.

For instance:

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL
```

or

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears
```

But don't expect much improvement in fps with this adapter.

Comment: Cool. Is there a way to make the AMD adapter the default one?

Comment: There is no need to make it default. You can set programs that may require it to run with `DRI_PRIME=1` by editing their shortcuts in `/usr/share/applications`. making it default will take much more power used with no benefit. But you can always add `DRI_PRIME=1` to `/etc/environment`.

Comment: Thanks man. You have been awesome! Now what if I am using PlayOnLinux? Will adding it to the PlayOnLinux shortcut also effect the game it's running or do I have to add it somewhere else?

Comment: Runing everything with the prefix will have this effect.